# Which is "the most memorable, mind-changing photograph of all time" that Galen Rowell talks about?

Tags: amateur, history

Galen Rowell in one of his books talks about the "The most memorable, mind-changing photograph of all time. A color landscape shot taken without a tripod by an amateur". Does anyone have a link to a copy of this or can explain what is special about it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Earthrise](http://waltgordonjones.com/3/galen-rowell-on-the-greatest-landscape-photograph-ever-taken) by Apollo 8 Astronaut William Anders - sounds like he was advocating that sometimes all the training or equipment doesn't make a photograph good, but sometimes a subject can be just THAT inspiring.

[image: Earthrise]
Credit: NASA

Comment: "Location, location, location."

Comment: Thats a whole different kind of weather sealing, eh?

Comment: As for equipment; Was this taken with the hasselblad?

Comment: this reminds me of "f8 and be there". also, hasselblad + zeiss lenses (http://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/a11-hass.html). recently they've changed to adapted pro nikon gear.