# How can you make the most of mobile phone cameras?

Tags: iphone, cameraphones, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the best results with a cell phone camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14119/how-do-i-get-the-best-results-with-a-cell-phone-camera)

I don't always have my DSLR with me, yet someone in the group usually has at least an iOS or Android device with them. Since I'm out in the country, most of the time they are less than 1MP cameras.

How can I make the most of my photos with these devices? My guess is that the right software (or apps) and perhaps multiple shots will go a long way in producing something that is reasonable.

Comment: The duplicate above is already our top hit for Android, and top 3 for the other tags. It is a duplicate. The answer below should be merged by a mod and I've flagged it as such.