# Photo Editing vs Manipulation vs Enhancement

Tags: photo-editing

I am evaluating various cameras and as i am checking GoPro, there is lots of talk about Go Pro photo app which can help you work on photo after you have clicked it.
I can understand some minor editing might be needed after you click photos to remove some unwanted stuff from photos but Photo apps seems to be doing the job of almost a camera and people can enhance photos like anything.

In photography world where do you draw the line, are there any standards which one needs to adhere to while editing the photo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where lays the border between correcting photo and creating a new one using PC?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/37947/where-lays-the-border-between-correcting-photo-and-creating-a-new-one-using-pc)