# Photo Competition 2021-11-15: Landscapes

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Landscapes

Candidates:
 1. Open wide areas with some point of interest.
 2. Mountains/Valleys.

Open wide areas are a must. "Close ups" shots of a tree/hut won't be acceptable.

This theme was suggested by [Aquarius_Girl](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/5205/aquarius-girl).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](//photo.stackexchange.com/questions/126700/photo-competition-2021-11-15-landscapes?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on November 29, 2021 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Comment: Are we allowed to [gently] critique any particular entry? Should I raise this on Meta?

Comment: @Tetsujin please raise this on Meta. As I understand it, in years past, there was some room for critiques in the photo contests then, and ultimately it didn't end well. Definitely worth a discussion in Meta where there's more room for editing, voting, and nuanced comment chains, than here.

Comment: done. Raised on meta as https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7198/57929 [feel free to critique/modify the question itself if needs be.]

Comment: Now I remember why we've been avoiding landscapes for so long. (They're most all subjects that have been done to death by hundreds of thousands of photographers. Many of them are so over processed they might as well be CGI - and I'm not convinced one or two of them aren't CGI or 3D rendered vectors from topo data.)

Comment: Apparently just discussing the possibility of critique has got some folks firing up the ole flamethrowers...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Grand Tetons at Sunrise**
[image: Grand Tetons]

Grand Tetons at Sunrise, Snake River Overlook
Nikon D800, 24-70mm @34mm, 1/40, f/8, ISO 100

Answer (score 30):

**Sheenjek River, Fall Colors, Arctic National Wildlife Refuge, Alaska**

[image: Sheenjek]

4 Sep 2017
Nikon D7000, 18-140 lens, 30mm, f/8, 1/125, ISO 320

Fall colors above the Sheenjek River near Double Mountain, about 240km (150mi) north of the Arctic Circle.

Comment: Puzzle! Puzzle!

Comment: @Joshua Yikes, nasty foreground!

Answer (score 30):

### Milky Way Over Sequoia

[image]

Sequoia National Park, June 26th 2021

Nikon D500 with Nikkor 18-140

f/3.5, 20 seconds, ISO400

Answer (score 29):

**Sunset at Lønstrup, Denmark,**

August 30 2020.[image]
Nikon D850, TAMRON SP 24-70mm F/2.8 Di VC USD G2 A032N, F2.8, 24mm, 1/25 Sec,ISO 100

Answer (score 28):

**Lonely House**
[image: Lonely House, Iceland]

Lonely House, Iceland
Fujifilm XT-3, XF18-135 @35mm 1/420, f/5.6, ISO160

Answer (score 27):

**Winnats Pass**

[image]

Derbyshire, England
June 2021
Fujifilm X-T3, XF35mm
f/8, 1/420, ISO 160

Answer (score 25):

#### No Mountains

Everyone's posting mountains. Enough!

[image]

About half way between Rotterdam and Utrecht ([51.95010 N 4.80599 E](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=51.95010+N+4.80599+E)), September 2019.

DJI FC220 (Mavic Pro), f/2.2 1/25 ISO 166 (must have a filter, most likely ND16 PL).

Answer (score 17):

[image]

## Eriskay Beach with Ferry

Camera: Lumix GX9
Lens: 12-60@36
Settings: f10, 1/400 sec, ISO 200

Answer (score 17):

**Hintersee, Berchtesgaden**

[image: Photo of Hintersee, Berchtesgaden]

```
November 11th, 2019
Olympus E-M5 Mark II
12-40mm F2.8 Lens
ISO 200, F4, 17mm, 1/1000s
```

Answer (score 16):

#### Landmannalaugar, Iceland

[image]

One of my most amazing hikes ever; basically a completely new landscape every hour. And a nice bath in the hot spring at the camp site to top it off.

August 21st, 2018
iPhone 7 Plus, f/1.8, 1/1546
Exact location: 63° 56' 57,822" N, 19° 2' 5,8" W

Answer (score 14):

### Golden Gate

[image]

San Francisco, July 7th 2021

Nikon D500 with Nikkor 18-140

f/4, 1/1000, ISO100

Answer (score 12):

[image: Morning Light, Plaza Blanca]

## Morning Light, Plaza Blanca

Plaza Blanca, New Mexico, April 9, 2019

Camera: Nikon D3400
Lens: 18-70@29

Comment: Location and Date/ (at least what season).

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Beach at the North Sea, Germany.

August 2020
Nikon D5300, 18mm, 1/320, f/13, ISO 100

Comment: What camera make & model?

Comment: @spikey_richie added it to the post

Comment: Is this a crop? It doesn't really *feel* like 18mm. But maybe it's just me. The tones are very enjoyable though.

Comment: @MrUpsidown The camera has an APS-C sensor, so the angle of view is the same as a 27mm on a FF sensor.

Comment: Ah yes, obviously!

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Ice fog over Yellowknife as seen from across Frame Lake, air temp -38 C without windchill

Iphone 6, default settings, 12 jan 2020

Answer (score 9):

[image]

## The Old Man of Storr

Camera: Lumix GX9
Lens: 12-60@12
Settings: f7.1, 1/400 sec, ISO 200

Answer (score 9):

**Click to enlarge**

A panoramic shot of the Elizabethan Garden at Kenilworth Castle in England.

Taken with a Pixel 4a.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

### Brecon Beacons, two days ago

Sunrise from [Pen y Fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pen_y_Fan) (Wales) on Monday (2021-11-15).  I slept in my van in the car park and hiked up in the drizzle and dark, only for it to brighten up when I got to the top.

Canon EOS 1100D, Sigma 17-80 at 17mm with IS. Stitched from 7 images using Hugin.

[image: Pen y Fan sunrise]

I'm in 2 minds about the lens flare, was tempted to edit it out but in the end left it.

Comment: I thought I had the originals on this machine but don't so lack the exposure details for now

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Misty morning on the Saint James way and over the Garonne, September 2019

KODAK 35mm Single Use Camera

Answer (score 9):

**View of Mount's Bay**

Taken on the 3rd of June 2021

Location: Trehenmere Sculpture Garden, nr Penzance, Cornwall, United Kingdom

Camera: Samsung Galaxy A10 phone camera.[image]

Answer (score 9):

### Marvel Lake and Marvel Peak from Wonder Pass, BC/Alberta border

This was on the tail end of a roughly 30km day hike. The photo doesn't come close to doing the scene justice. I'd recommend the hike for anyone able to do it.

Nikon D850, Sigma 14-24mm f/2.8 @ 19mm and f/6.3 and 1/640th, ISO 250. De-noising in DxO PureRAW and light post-processing in Lightroom.

September 26th, 2021, about an hour or two before sundown.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**Becalmed**

[image: Becalmed]

June 2020

Dalyan Park, Fenerbahçe, Kadikoy, Istanbul, Turkey

Camera: Canon AE-1 Program

Film: Ilford HP5 Plus 400 pushed to 800

Self developed, scanned using Epson V370.

Answer (score 7):

Probably a "seascape" instead of a "landscape", but anyway:
"Varadero Beach Sunset" (if you need a title)

Taken in 2015 at Varadero beach (Cuba) on sunset. Taken with a Panasonic GH-3 1/320 at f=9, ISO 200, focal length 64mm equivalent.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

### Denali National Park

[image]

Denali, August 4th 2021

Nikon D500 with Nikkor 18-140

f/4, 1/1250, ISO100

Answer (score 6):

**Warwick from up high**

Warwick town centre, looking towards St. Marys church on the right. This was taken from the top of Guy's Tower at Warwick Castle.

OMD E-M10 mk iii,
ƒ/5.6,
1/125,
25 mm,
ISO200

[image]

Comment: Where's the sky ?

Comment: 1/3rd sky, 2/3rds scenery. It was a very cloudy day, so it does look very white. Although, looking again, it's more 1/4 sky. Looks like I missed my 3rds this time.

Comment: 1/5th, that is. Sadly the sky is burnt and the photo is not leveled.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

11 mile marker on Barr Trail

Taken with iPhone camera 14 Nov 2021

Comment: Is it not level intentionally?

Comment: Unintentional: cold powerful winds made it difficult to take good photos.

Comment: You know you can adjust it later, right? The iPhone has great editing tools built in.

Comment: Not sure if editing after the fact is allowed.

Comment: Looking at the other images, I would assume so. See also https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/124876/how-to-check-if-a-photo-is-edited-even-basic-edits-like-exposure-and-white-bala and https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/122129/a-camera-that-takes-real-photos-without-manipulation-like-old-analog-cameras/122137#122137

Answer (score 5):

I call this "Morning Fog", taken in October 2017, in the Bavarian Forest (Untergriesbach, Bavaria, Germany).
Camera was a Panasonic GH-3, 1/400 at f=5.6, focal length 47mm (equivalent), ISO 200.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Schleswig-Holstein, Germany

April 2015

Canon EOS 1000D @18mm

f/3.5, 1/80, ISO 800

Comment: 40% of the frame is pitch black. Was there really nothing for us to see in that foreground?

Comment: A harvested field. Not that interesting, I guess, while the horizon looks like it could be somewhere in the Serengeti.

Comment: Then I'd have cropped it and probably changed the aspect ratio to panorama, maybe 3:1, removing most of that empty black area, and that tree on the left to keep just the background trees and interesting bits of the sky...

Answer (score 3):

**Yachats**

[image]

August 11, 2016

My parents’ best friends’ house, about 10 miles up the Yachats River on the Oregon coast, along with some of their greenhouses where they grow organic herbs and vegetables to sell to fancy restaurants up and down the coast.

Canon EOS 6D, 85mm, f/5.6, 1/320 second, ISO 100

Answer (score 3):

I call this one "Afternoon Sunflowers", taken October 2015 near Nittenau, Bavaria, Germany with a Panasonic GH-3, 1/320 at f=7 with an equivalent focal length of 190mm at ISO 200:
[image]

Comment: Sadly, the top of the house is missing and the shadows seem completely blocked.

Comment: We shouldn't discuss here, but yes: Above the "house" a few pixels are missing, but for the shadows: Imagine a bright sunny afternoon, and a dense forest; would you really see any details in the shadow? Despite of that, there *are* some details in the shadows, but maybe JPG compression "eat them up".

Answer (score 2):

[image: Vegas Mountain Trail]

The jpeg was 3mb so i had to crop it to make it fit in the post.

Taken with Canon EOS Rebel T7, June 2021.

Comment: Where was this taken and where's the sky ?

Comment: It was somewhere between the entrance of the Hoover Dam and parking garage, it was a very cloudy day.